# What's the root cause "contract error - Gas estimation failed Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below)"?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, evm

Rest of the error:

> The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force
>   sending?  Internal JSON-RPC error.

I got that message on several cases, usually on different mistakes.

What's the cause for that error and is there a way which can get me towards understanding the problem faster.

In most cases I'm trying to rewrite everything chunk by chunk and check when I don't get that error.

Comment: This is a general error message, share your code so that people can take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among other things, every Ethereum transaction has attribute named `gasLimit` or simply `gas`.  This is the maximum amount of gas transaction is allowed to consume.  When sending transaction via Web3 API, you may specify value for this attribute explicitly:

```js
web3.eth.sendTransaction ({
  from: 0x0123456789012345678901234567890123456789,
  to: 0x9876543210987654321098765432109876543210,
  gas: 90000 // <-- Here is gasLimit
});
```

This parameter is optional, and if it is omitted, Web3 API implementation will try to estimate proper value by first executing transaction locally before actually broadcasting it to the network.  This local execution is similar to how miners execute transaction before including them into blocks.

In case local execution succeeds, Web3 API implementation counts how much gas transaction actually consumed and uses this value to populate `gasLimit` parameter.  Though, in case local execution failed, e.g. smart contract reverted it, `gas estimation failed` error is reported.  You may still broadcast such transaction by explicitly specifying `gasLimit` for it.